# Difference between <T extends A> void foo(T t) and void foo(A a)

Tags: java, generics

Say `A` is an interface. What is the difference between

```
public <T extends A> void foo(T t) { ... }
```

and

```
public void foo(A a) { ...}
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not much.

On the other hand, consider this method:

```
public <T extends A> T transform(T t);
```

And caller code:

```
class B implements A { ... }
B result = transform(new B(...));
```

It wouldn't be possible (above wouldn't compile, as compiler would force you to declare `result` type as `A`) had you declared method as

```
public A transform(A a)
```

Comment: This is also true if you have a return type.

Comment: "had you declared f as", what does the `f` mean?

Answer (score 8):

There isn't a difference when using one object. But imagine if you had

```
class B extends A { ... }
```

and

```
public void f(List<A> list) { ... };
```

and

```
public <T extends A> void f(List<T> list) { ... };
```

with the first one you can pass a list that is exactly of type `List<A>`. With the second one you can pass a list which contains objects that extend `A`. However, with the first one you cannot do the same thing. So in other words you could not pass `List<B>` to the first method but you could to the second method.

Comment: for the second case you can still write `public void f(List<? extends A> list);`

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference in your case because the type parameter is used in one place only. Both methods will accept anything that is an A or extends A. The generic method would make more sense in this case because the type parameter let you tie the return value to the passed parameter:

```
public <T extends A> T f(Class<T>) {...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether it makes a difference depends on what's inside that function.

The point of generics is to insure type safety. Suppose A has two subclasses, let's call them B and C. In the first example, using f(List<A>), the list could include B's, C's, or a mixture of both. But in the second example, f<T extends A>(List<T>), when we invoke the function we must specify the type. If we say f<B>, then we know this is a list of B's, no C's allowed. We will not be allowed to pass in a list of C's or generic A's, we cannot add any C's to the list, and anything we take out will be guaranteed to be a B.

Whether this is good or bad depends on what you're trying to do. If the idea is that you want a list that is either all B or all C, then the generic helps guarantee this. If you want a list that can be a mix of the two, then you don't want to use the generic, use the simple f(List<A>).

Comment: what examples are you referring to?

Comment: By "examples" I meant the two function declarations the original poster gave: the "<T extends A> f(List<T>)" and "f(List<A>)". Okay, maybe they weren't really "examples".

Comment: I don't see that in the question; only in one of the answers

Comment: The question begins, "Say A is an interface. What is the difference between". The next line is the first function declaration that i refer to as an "example". Then it says "or" and he gives the next example. Is this text not appearing correctly in your browser, or are we not understanding each other?

Comment: There are no `List<T>` or `List<A>` in his question; only `T` and `A`

Comment: Whoops, sorry! Going back and forth between question and answers I confused an answer with the original question! Well, the question's getting stale anyway, not sure there's a point in updating my answer to clarify beyond this comment.